# Bit twiddling reorder

Tags: bit-manipulation, shuffle

I need to do an arbitrary reorder of a 7 bit value (Yes I know I should be using a table) and am wondering if there are any bit hacks to do this.

Example:

```
// <b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6> -> <b3, b2, b4, b1, b5, b0, b6>

// the naive way
out =
   (0x020 & In) << 5 |
   (0x008 & In) << 2 |
   (0x040 & In)      |
   (0x012 & In) >> 1 |
   (0x004 & In) >> 2 |
   (0x001 & In) >> 3;

// 6 ANDs, 5 ORs, 5 shifts = 16 ops
```

---

*edit:*
I was thinking of something along the lines of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/devdev/archive/2005/12/12/502980.aspx)

Just for kicks and because I was AFTK I'm trying a brute force search for solutions of the form:

```
((In * C1) >> C2) & 0x7f
```

No solutions found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the compiler output of your "naive" code, it might surprise you. I once did something like that and the compiler (VC++2005) completely changed the values of all the ands and shifts for me to make them more efficient, eg  I'm sure it would remove your "(0x001 & In) >> 3".

But yes, if the reshuffle is a fixed function then a table is probably best.

**Update**

For a laugh I looked at the compiler output from VC++ 2005....

First I tried a constant value for "In" but the compiler wasn't fooled one bit, it produced this code:

```
mov eax,469h
```

ie. it completely optimized it away.

So ... I tried a proper input and got this:

```
00401D4F  mov         eax,ecx 
00401D51  and         eax,20h 
00401D54  shl         eax,3 
00401D57  mov         edx,ecx 
00401D59  and         edx,8 
00401D5C  or          eax,edx 
00401D5E  mov         edx,ecx 
00401D60  sar         edx,1 
00401D62  and         edx,2 
00401D65  or          edx,ecx 
00401D67  sar         edx,1 
00401D69  shl         eax,2 
00401D6C  and         edx,9 
00401D6F  or          eax,edx 
00401D71  and         ecx,40h 
00401D74  or          eax,ecx
```

That's four shift operations, five ANDs, four ORs - not bad for six inputs. Probably better than most people could do by hand.

It's probably also optimized for out-of-order execution so it'll be less clock cycles than it seems.  :-)

Comment: 16 ops in, 16 ops out. I'll bet the only difference is how well code pipelines (no small matter)

Answer (score 5):

The first step seems to be to understand a mathematical solution and optimize that.

see here of [bit hacks](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of bit-twiddling hacks for common operations, i.e. to reverse the order of the bits in a 32-bit word (10 each of shift, AND and OR, AFAICR).

In this case, with an apparently completely arbitrary mapping from input to output, I can't see any way of cleaning this up.

Use a lookup table :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you optimize, you should make sure your 'naive' way is doing what you intend.  If I make your code into a function and run this loop:

```
for (b=0;b<7;b++)
{
    i=1<<b;
    printf("%d: %02x -> %02x\n", b, i, shuffle(i));
}
```

It produces this output, which contradicts the comments. In fact, it loses bits.

```
0: 01 -> 00
1: 02 -> 01
2: 04 -> 01
3: 08 -> 20
4: 10 -> 08
5: 20 -> 00
6: 40 -> 40
```

In order to get the shuffle you describe, I would code it like this:

```
   //    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
   //-> 3 2 4 1 5 0 6
   (0x001 & In) << 3 |
   (0x004 & In) << 2 |
   (0x020 & In)      |
   (0x012 & In) << 1 |
   (0x008 & In) >> 2 |
   (0x020 & In) >> 5 ;
```

Comment: Oops. I should have been more clear: the comment is bit positions.

Comment: There still seems like there is something off with your implementation.  For example: the term `(0x001 & In) >> 3` will be 0 regardless of the value of In.  Likewise '(0x020 & In) << 5' moves bit5 to bit 10.